# How to save multiple .txt files as .csv files without any delimiter in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have multiple .txt files which have data as per below format in single line

```
MACADD||TEST|Street1|CITY||Taiwan, Republic of China|||10000000|||FIRE||Taiwan||||||||12 days||30 Days|DDTE||812148709231890||124-Taiwan|DENE|||LDE
```

I am trying to save these .txt files as .csv files in such a way that the entire data string appears in 1st cell of the .csv file.

I can achieve this by quoting the entire data string in " " but the problem is when I again process the .csv files to generate XML files then those inverted commas become a problem. For example, the 1st data will appear as "MACADD and last one as LDE" which is not accepted by the system.

Comment: Use standard processing with export-csv and import-csv and all systems should use the standard csv rule. Alternatively, convert the String to json but I dont think this is necessary in this scenario...

Comment: I did that too but that is generating empty .csv file
import-csv F:\Newfolder\n.txt | export-csv F:\Newfolder\n.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Import-CSV expects a header, please check if this is fullfilled. And specify the delimiter if you want to process the files. Otherwise, if you need no processind, also check get-content and set-content as alternative, as they provide better possibilities for raw processing. The CSV CMDlets are better if the csv file needs internal processing with powershell objects.

Comment: Instead of using CSV files which expect headers and are by definition delimited, try using the Add-Content cmdlet to just add the lines to your text file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7

Comment: @LordPupazz, I think we have slightly deviated from main topic, I just want to convert the .txt file which has the data as per the above-mentioned problem statement into .csv file. the conversion should happen in such a way that data should not split into multiple columns.

Comment: the fix is to make a VALID csv file. that means that you MUST enclose any column that contains a delimiter in quotes OR you must use a different delimiter. **_CSV does not stand for `comma separated value` ... it stands for `character separated value`.**_ so you MUST obey the format requirements and either enclose the columns in quotes OR use delimiters that are not used in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-Content` to import it and `out-csv` to export it, because you don't really need csv formatting:

### Single File:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt | Out-File C:\temp\test.csv
```

### Multiple Files in one Folder:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
foreach ($file in $files){
    $newFileName = ($file.Fullname) -Replace ".txt",".csv"
    Get-Content $file.FullName | Out-File $newFileName
}
```

Please test it, let me know if it worked and if it did, please mark the post as the answer.

Comment: it worked for a single file, how to make it work for multiple files

Comment: @Nishant I am so glad it worked :) Have a nice day. The good thing would be that you understand the full code so you can do something like that for yourself. That's way more efficient than. :O